# Issue with tensor shape when training a neural network with Pytorch and PennyLane

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, quantum-computing

I am trying to run a quantum neural network with a custom gym environment. The code for the custom gym environment is this: https://github.com/dimikout3/MarsExplorer/blob/main/mars-explorer/mars_explorer/envs/explorer.py. Furthermore, my specific code follows this same structure: https://github.com/qdevpsi3/qrl-dqn-gym/blob/main/cart_pole/colab_notebook.ipynb. Here is the error that I am currently encountering:

```
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:498: UserWarning: WARN: Overriding environment explorer-v1 already in registry.
  logger.warn(f"Overriding environment {new_spec.id} already in registry.")
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:20: UserWarning: WARN: It seems a Box observation space is an image but the `dtype` is not `np.uint8`, actual type: float32. If the Box observation space is not an image, we recommend flattening the observation to have only a 1D vector.
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:25: UserWarning: WARN: It seems a Box observation space is an image but the upper and lower bounds are not in [0, 255]. Generally, CNN policies assume observations are within that range, so you may encounter an issue if the observation values are not.
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:174: UserWarning: WARN: Future gym versions will require that `Env.reset` can be passed a `seed` instead of using `Env.seed` for resetting the environment random number generator.
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:187: UserWarning: WARN: Future gym versions will require that `Env.reset` can be passed `options` to allow the environment initialisation to be passed additional information.
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:195: UserWarning: WARN: The result returned by `env.reset()` was not a tuple of the form `(obs, info)`, where `obs` is a observation and `info` is a dictionary containing additional information. Actual type: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:219: DeprecationWarning: WARN: Core environment is written in old step API which returns one bool instead of two. It is recommended to rewrite the environment with new step API.
  logger.deprecation(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:225: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(done, (bool, np.bool8)):
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:141: UserWarning: WARN: The obs returned by the `step()` method was expecting numpy array dtype to be float32, actual type: float64
  logger.warn(
C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\utils\passive_env_checker.py:165: UserWarning: WARN: The obs returned by the `step()` method is not within the observation space.
  logger.warn(f"{pre} is not within the observation space.")
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.11.7)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
DQN:   0%|          | 0/5000 [00:00<?, ?episode/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 238, in <module>
    env = gym.make('explorer-v1')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 581, in make
    env_creator = load(spec_.entry_point)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 61, in load
    mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 718, in <module>
    trainer.learn(total_episodes,
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 557, in learn
    train_stats = self.train_step()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 499, in train_step
    loss = self.update_net()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 455, in update_net
    state_action_values = self.net(states)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\Documents\MarsExplorer\explorerEnv\explorerEnv.py", line 658, in forward
    outputs = self.q_layers(inputs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\pennylane\qnn\torch.py", line 402, in forward
    results = self._evaluate_qnode(inputs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\pennylane\qnn\torch.py", line 429, in _evaluate_qnode
    res = [torch.reshape(r, (x.shape[0], -1)) for r in res]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kwasi\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.7\Lib\site-packages\pennylane\qnn\torch.py", line 429, in <listcomp>
    res = [torch.reshape(r, (x.shape[0], -1)) for r in res]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: shape '[7056, -1]' is invalid for input of size 4
```

If it matters, I am not running this in a notebook, but rather with Python on my local computer. I also had to make a few minor changes to the code to correct earlier errors, including adding a seed() attribute to the custom environment.

I examined the neural network structure in order to see if there were any specific areas that interacted with the tensor shape. I unfortunately could not find anything, and am unsure what in the code could be causing this.